# Changing python list size during iteration. Is it okay?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)): 
    a.pop(0)
    print ('%d/%d' % (i, len(a)))
```

Above is simple code changes list size during iterating itself.

```
$ python test.py
0/4
1/3
2/2
3/1
4/0
```

And the result was like above.
From `2/2`, `i` exceed the total iteration size!

***Question***
Could anyone tell me why the code still executes after exceeding the size?

Comment: `range(len(a))` is evaluated only once.

Comment: Maybe conceptualize it as: `r = range(len(a))`, then `for i in r:`?

Comment: Because you are iterating over a `range` object, not the list you are `.pop`ing from

Comment: as others have explained you're not actually iterating the list in your example, because you take the length of it at the beginning, then iterate over that integer range. If you instead actually iterate over the list elements themselves, and change the length of the list, you can also get unexpected results. It is generally not advisable to modify a list while iterating over it, and what you have done (iterate over an integer range instead) is a common solution (though you do need to be aware of the length changing and possible index out of range issues...).

Answer (score 3):

hmm... for easier explanation, what happened here is

when you run `for i in range(len(a)):`

it will automatically run `for i in range(5):`

so it will not call the len function again and again for each loop

This is another example:

```
length=5
for i in range(length):
    length=2
    print(length)
```

the result is

```
2
2
2
2
2
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think most of for iteration (any language) is fixed since beginning, if you want to loop something that is not fixed, better use while

```
length=5
i=0
while i < length:
    length=2
    print(length)
    i+=1
```

The result

```
2
2
```

Comment: you should include an example to demonstrate this (but yes it is absolutely correct i think )